# How to retreive Reported properties from ModuleClient

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I am looking for a way to get the full reported twin properties for the iot module by using the ModuleClient. Is there a way to do this?

I am using the azure-iot-sdk-java library with Java 11.

So far I have just found ways to retreive the desired properties.

Comment: May I know what documents you have referred so far?

Comment: Just checking back, could you please let us know if you need further help in this matter.